# Number of singularities of a vector field in a compact manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-fields, singularity

I'm studying the Gauss-Bonnet theorem flor a compact surfaces using the ideas in the paper of Chern (1944). My principal source of this approach is the master thesis of Otto Romero "El Teorema de Gauss-Bonnet en Variedades Suaves". There he choose a point $p$ in a compact, orientable surface $M$, take a neighborhood of $p$ and then choose a vector field $X$ whose unique singular point is $p$.

I do not understand why we can choose such vector field. I know that in a compact manifold we can choose a vector field with a finite numbers of singular points but it doesn't need to be necessarily one with only a singular point.

Such construction reduce significantly calculations but I don'k know if he do that only for that or if there exist an argument who allow me to do that.

I will be grateful if you help to solve this doubt.

Comment: I don't see the point of making this argument, although it is correct. Why not work with a vector field with a finite number of zeroes and make Chern's Stokes's Theorem argument by removing a finite number of balls? The 1944 paper is far more sophisticated than anything you need. Take a look at Section 3.3 of my [undergraduate differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your answer and for share your book! Is a nice one, I really like it, I will read it with more details. The idea is that I want to prove using Chern's argument. What I really want is to do the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem without using characteristics clases for my bachelor thesis, but is a lot of theory (specially from topology ) so I decided to do prove the theorem only for surfaces, using the theory diffential manifolds that I was studying. Thank you again for the book.

Comment: Yes, for surfaces Chern's argument is very simple and is just the structure equations together with Stokes's Theorem.